# Plot the hist using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below is the dataframe

```
             Quantity   UnitPrice   CustomerID
Country         
Netherlands  200128     6492.55     34190538.0
EIRE         142637     48447.19    110391745.0
Germany      117448     37666.00    120075093.0
France       110480     43031.99    107648864.0
Australia    83653      4054.75     15693002.0
```

How to plot a histogram with condition x axis as country(rotate 90) and Quanity on Y axis

`df.hist(x,y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
df.plot.bar(y='Quantity')
```

Here's the output:
[image]

Comment: so why don't we need to give the x axis ?

Comment: Because it is set to be the `index` of the data frame by default. You can be even more explicit like this: `df.plot.bar(y='Quantity', use_index=True)`